# Let $[e_1,e_2,e_3]$ and $[ f_1, f_2, f_3]$ be ordered bases of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Which of the following functions from $V$ to $V$ are linear maps? Using the definition of a linear map, justify your answers. (You may not assume that $V = \mathbb{R^3}$)

(a) $T(x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3) = |x_1| f_1 + x_3 f_3$

(b) $S(x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3) = (x_1 + x_2)f_1$

I've looked through my notes but I can't find anything that is in any way similar to this so really any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the definitions? Write down for us what you have to prove or refute in terms of that definition.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698661/linear-maps-of-vector-spaces-with-irdered-bases/2698664#2698664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

We have
$$Te_1 = T(-e_1) = f_1$$
Can $T$ be linear?

---

Show that $$S(\alpha (x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3) + \beta (y_1e_1 + y_2e_2 + y_3e_3) ) = \alpha S(x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3) + \beta S(y_1e_1 + y_2e_2 + y_3e_3)$$

and conclude that $S$ is linear.

Comment: I understand what you've said for part (b) which is just to apply one of the properties/criteria for a linear map. Thank you. But how do you know that the first statement is true? i.e. how do you know that $T(e_1) = T(-e_1) = f_1$? I don't understand how you got that from what we're given about T.

Comment: @MathWolf If $T$ were linear, then we would have $$f_1 = T(-e_1) = -Te_1 = -f_1$$
because  $T(\alpha x) = \alpha Tx$ for all $x \in V$ and scalars $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you.